# Given the equality $F_{X\cdot Y} = F_X \cdot F_Y$ of distribution functions, are $X,Y$ independent?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

There is the well-known characterization that random variables $X,Y$ are independent if and only if $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F_X (x) \cdot F_Y (y)$. Due to a typo in a draft for an exam that I recently checked, this question was mis-stated as follows:

> If $X,Y$ are real-valued random variables such that $F_{X \cdot Y} = F_X \cdot F_Y$, does it follow that $X,Y$ are stochastically independent?

Here, $F_{X \cdot Y}$ is the distribution function of the product $X \cdot Y$, i.e., $F_{X\cdot Y}(t) = \Bbb{P}(X\cdot Y \leq t)$. The assumption means more explicitly that $F_{X \cdot Y}(t) = F_X(t) \cdot F_Y (t)$ for all $t \in \Bbb{R}$.

I would guess that the answer to the question is "no". The trouble I have with proving this is that it is difficult for me to construct at all random variables $X,Y$ (independent or not) which satisfy $F_{X \cdot Y} = F_X \cdot F_Y$, except when $X$ or $Y$ are (almost surely) constant, in which case the claimed independence trivially holds.

One further observation: If $X,Y$ are indeed independent, then
$$
F_X (t) \cdot F_Y(t)
= \Bbb{P}(X \leq t) \cdot \Bbb{P}(Y \leq t)
= \Bbb{P}(X \leq t \text{ and } Y \leq t)
= \Bbb{P}(\max\{X,Y\} \leq t)
= F_{\max \{X,Y\}}(t).
$$
Thus, if the claim was true, we would have $F_{X \cdot Y} = F_{\max \{X,Y\}}$, meaning that $X \cdot Y \sim \max \{X,Y\}$. But even using this, I am unable to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Your question for  the independent case remains unanswered so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I made an arithmetic error, taking $X = Y$ with cdf $$F_X(t) = \begin{cases}
0,\ t \leqslant 1\\
\exp\left(\frac{-1}{\log t}\right)
\end{cases}$$
gives a counterexample.

$$P(X \cdot Y \leqslant t) =
P(X^2 \leqslant t) =
P(X \leqslant \sqrt{t}) =\\
F_X(\sqrt{t})=\\
\exp\left(\frac{-1}{\log\sqrt{t}}\right)=
\exp\left(\frac{-2}{\log t}\right) = \left(\exp\left(\frac{-1}{\log t}\right)\right)^2=\\
F_X(t)^2 = F_X(t)\cdot F_Y(t) = P(X \leqslant t) \cdot P(Y \leqslant t)
$$

(to find this example I assumed $X = Y$, got equation $f(\sqrt{t}) = f(t)^2$ and asked [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28sqrt%28t%29%29%20%3D%20%28f%28t%29%29%5E2))

Comment: That is an interesting probability distribution. I just noticed that
$$\exp(-\frac{1}{\log( \exp( - \frac{1}{\log t}))}) = t$$
so $\exp(-\frac{1}{\log t})$ is both the CDF and the quantile function ! (although the domain is not the same.)

Comment: I agree, very oddly specific cdf to be determined by an easy relation like $F_{X^2} = F_X^2$.

Comment: Actually, after some substitutions we can get $F_X(t) = \exp(p(\frac{1}{\ln t}))$, where $p(t)$ satisfies $p(2t) = 2p(t)$, so it should not be surprising we have such small set of solutions.